# Searching for an item in a list that's nested inside another list based on a property value in C# using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to search for an item in a list that's nested inside another list based on a property value using LINQ?

Given the follow models below, for a given Order (variable `customerOrder`), I want to return the earliest order date (`Date`) where the Day is "Sunday".

models:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDate> OrderDates { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDate
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
}
```

code:

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
foreach(var a in customerOrder.OrderLines)
{
    var orderDate = a.OrderDates.Where(x => x.DateTypeId.Equals("Sunday")).FirstOrDefault();
    dates.Add(orderDate.ActualDate);
}
dates.OrderBy(d => d.Date);

return dates.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**
More elegant query

You can use Linq to achieve your result.

Here is a query that would closely mimick your code.

```cs
customerOrder.OrderLines
    .Select(ol => ol.OrderDates
        .Where(x => x.Day.Equals("Sunday"))
        .FirstOrDefault())
    .Where(d => d != null)
    .OrderBy(d => d.Date)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

which could be more elegantly rewritten as:

```cs
customerOrder.OrderLines
    .SelectMany(ol => ol.OrderDates)
    .OrderBy(d => d.Date)
    .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Day == "Sunday");
```

Here is a Linqpad query with some test data and dump for you to try.
Simply copy and paste in Linqpad.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var customerOrder = new Order
    {
        Id = 1,
        OrderLines = Enumerable
            .Range(0, 10)
            .Select(i => new OrderLine
            {
                Description = $"Line Description {i}",
                OrderDates = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                    .Select(j => new OrderDate
                    {
                        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i+j),
                        Day = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i+j).DayOfWeek.ToString()
                    })
                    .ToList()
            })
            .ToList()
        }
        .Dump();

    customerOrder.OrderLines
        .SelectMany(ol => ol.OrderDates)
        .OrderBy(d => d.Date)
        .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Day == "Sunday")
        .Dump();
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDate> OrderDates { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDate
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
}
```

On a side note the `OrderDate` class is not necessary. The `DateTime` type has a property `DayOfWeek` that you can use to test is a Date is a Sunday.

`DayOfWeek` is an enum so you can simply test `MyDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday` rather than relying on a `string` for that purpose.

Comment: How does it compare with my approach in terms of efficiency btw or is it negligible?

Comment: I'd say it should be comparable. But if you really want to make sure, you need to benchmark it. I use BenchmarkDotNet for this kind of activity: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet . But I really would not bother about performance unless there is a strong reason for that.

Comment: @Alexander makes also a very good point about the fact that a Linq query does not mutate the data which is queried (see the beginning of his answer). He pointed to a bug of your implementation (@Alenxander, I did +1 on your answer, and edited my answer to make a more elegant request based on yours and @JoshuaRobinson).

Answer (score 3):

First of all your code will not work as intended.
`dates.OrderBy(d => d.Date);` doesn't work: [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) returns an IEnumerable, it doesn't change the original collection. You should either use [`List.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort)` or do this:

```
dates = dates.OrderBy(d => d.Date).ToList()
```

Secondly, you use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault): it has an overload that accepts predicate to search with; so the [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) call is not needed. In addition FirstOrDefault will return `null` if nothing found. If this is a possible scenario, you should consider checking whether `orderDate` is null:

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
foreach(var a in customerOrder.OrderLines)
{
    var orderDate = a.OrderDates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DateTypeId.Equals("Sunday"));
    if (orderDate is {})
    {
        dates.Add(orderDate.ActualDate);
    }
}
dates = dates.OrderBy(d => d.Date).ToList();

return dates.FirstOrDefault();
```

That should work fine. But it hard to guess what aspects of behavior of your code samples are intended and what are not. You ask about searching, but say nothing about OrderBy part. Could you clarify this part, please?

Answering the question, if by `better` you mean more compact way, you can go with something like this:

```
var result = customerOrder.OrderLines
    .SelectMany(a => a.OrderDates)
    .OrderBy(d => d.Date)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DateTypeId.Equals("Sunday"));
return result;
```

You shouldn't be bothered with `better way` now; firstly you should start with at least `working way`. I suggest you to learn how to do these things both using Linq and without using Linq.

Answer (score 1):

Better is a bit subjective, but you can use the [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) extension method to flatten the `OrderDate` instances into one sequence.

Then you can use the [`Enumerable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) extension method to filter the dates that are `"Sunday"`.

Then you can use the [`Enumerable.Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min) extension method to get the minimum date.

All of this can be chained together into a single statement.

```
DateTime earliestSunday = customeOrder
   .OrderLines
   .SelectMany(ol => ol.OrderDates)
   .Where(od => od.Day == "Sunday")
   .Min(od => od.Date);
```

Comment: Beware if the collection contains no elements, the `Min` call will throw an exception.